# What is wrong with Korean displaying on the browser?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, fonts

When I display Korean letters on Google Chrome browser on Ubuntu Linux, I see that the fonts are rendered, but the spacing is wrong. It looks like this:

[image]

A close up:

[image]

What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Ubuntu do you have? This is a bug in the font rendering in Debian and Ubuntu. This bug will be fixed in the upcoming Ubuntu 14.04 version of Ubuntu. You can either upgrade to the [final beta version](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades) or use the command below to update the font.

```
$ wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-wqy-microhei/0.2.0-beta-2/+build/5404937/+files/ttf-wqy-microhei_0.2.0-beta-2_all.deb
$ wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-wqy-microhei/0.2.0-beta-2/+build/5404937/+files/fonts-wqy-microhei_0.2.0-beta-2_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure fonts-wqy-microhei_0.2.0-beta-2_all.deb ttf-wqy-microhei_0.2.0-beta-2_all.deb
```

You can read up on why this is happening in more detail [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=233851).